# Docker compose - Logstash unable to connect to elastic search

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash

I am trying to use filebeat, logstash, kibana and elasticsearch to read a log file on my windows laptop. I have docker for desktop installed. Please find below my project directory:

[image]

The docker compose file is shown below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.12.2
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - elk

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.12.2
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:8.12.2
    container_name: logstash
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200    
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/config/logstash.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
    command: logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.conf
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  filebeat:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.12.2
    command: filebeat -e -strict.perms=false
    container_name: filebeat
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./filebeat/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /var/lib/docker/containers:/var/lib/docker/containers
      - /var/log:/var/log
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge
```

The filebeat.yml is shown below:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - D:/Project/elk/elk-metric-demo/logs/metric-app.log

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["logstash:5000"]
```

The logstash.conf is shown below:

```
    input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}" 
  }
}
```

When I perform a docker compose up command all service start except logstash with the following error message:

```
    2024-03-23 11:53:47 [2024-03-23T07:53:47,472][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Failed to perform request {:message=>"Connect to elasticsearch:9200 [elasticsearch/172.25.0.2] failed: Connection refused", :exception=>Manticore::SocketException, :cause=>#<Java::OrgApacheHttpConn::HttpHostConnectException: Connect to elasticsearch:9200 [elasticsearch/172.25.0.2] failed: Connection refused>}
2024-03-23 11:53:47 [2024-03-23T07:53:47,475][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::SocketException] Connect to elasticsearch:9200 [elasticsearch/172.25.0.2] failed: Connection refused"}
2024-03-23 11:53:47 [2024-03-23T07:53:47,483][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Failed to perform request {:message=>"Connect to elasticsearch:9200 [elasticsearch/172.25.0.2] failed: Connection refused", :exception=>Manticore::SocketException, :cause=>#<Java::OrgApacheHttpConn::HttpHostConnectException: Connect to elasticsearch:9200 [elasticsearch/172.25.0.2] failed: Connection refused>}
2024-03-23 11:53:47 [2024-03-23T07:53:47,484][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Marking url as dead. Last error: [LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError] Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::SocketException] Connect to elasticsearch:9200 [elasticsearch/172.25.0.2] failed: Connection refused {:url=>http://elasticsearch:9200/, :error_message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::SocketException] Connect to elasticsearch:9200 [elasticsearch/172.25.0.2] failed: Connection refused", :error_class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError"}
2024-03-23 11:53:47 [2024-03-23T07:53:47,486][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempt to fetch Elasticsearch cluster info failed. Sleeping for 0.02 {:fail_count=>1, :exception=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::SocketException] Connect to elasticsearch:9200 [elasticsearch/172.25.0.2] failed: Connection refused"}
2024-03-23 11:53:47 [2024-03-23T07:53:47,507][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve Elasticsearch cluster info. {:message=>"No Available connections", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::NoConnectionAvailableError}
2024-03-23 11:53:47 [2024-03-23T07:53:47,508][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections"}
2024-03-23 11:53:47 [2024-03-23T07:53:47,524][ERROR][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Failed to fetch X-Pack information from Elasticsearch. This is likely due to failure to reach a live Elasticsearch cluster.
2024-03-23 11:53:47 [2024-03-23T07:53:47,533][INFO ][logstash.config.source.local.configpathloader] No config files found in path {:path=>"/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.conf"}
2024-03-23 11:53:47 [2024-03-23T07:53:47,534][ERROR][logstash.config.sourceloader] No configuration found in the configured sources.
2024-03-23 11:53:47 [2024-03-23T07:53:47,594][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600, :ssl_enabled=>false}
2024-03-23 11:53:47 [2024-03-23T07:53:47,603][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
2024-03-23 11:53:47 [2024-03-23T07:53:47,610][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
2024-03-23 11:53:47 org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
2024-03-23 11:53:47     at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:808) ~[jruby.jar:?]
2024-03-23 11:53:47     at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:767) ~[jruby.jar:?]
2024-03-23 11:53:47     at usr.share.logstash.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:90) ~[?:?]
2024-03-24 05:23:07 Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk

...
2024-03-24 05:23:38 [2024-03-24T01:23:38,849][INFO ][logstash.config.source.local.configpathloader] No config files found in path {:path=>"/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.conf"}
2024-03-24 05:23:38 [2024-03-24T01:23:38,851][ERROR][logstash.config.sourceloader] No configuration found in the configured sources.
2024-03-24 05:23:38 [2024-03-24T01:23:38,936][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600, :ssl_enabled=>false}
2024-03-24 05:23:38 [2024-03-24T01:23:38,955][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
2024-03-24 05:23:38 [2024-03-24T01:23:38,966][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
2024-03-24 05:23:38 org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
```

While starting  logstash in the terminal I can get access to elastic search as shown below:

[image]

However the logstash container cannot start successfully because it is unable to connect.
Any advice why i am doing wrong please?

Comment: You should use Logstash port as 5044 (default Logstash port) in your Filebeat output plugin instead of 5000. And the logs are just WARNs and INFOs. Isn't there any error message?

Comment: Addition to what Murat says, you should use logstash-input-beats instead of logstash-input-path `input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}` 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-beats.html

Comment: Hello @MusabDogan Thanks for the feedback but I have updated my answer with changes require but still get the same error message.

Comment: @MuratK. Thanks for the feedback and I have also added the error message to the logs still get the same error message,

Comment: hi, can you please change  hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"] in your logstash.conf file to hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]  and please make sure that you have configuration file in the right place. Because it says "No config files found in path {:path=>"/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.conf"}"